# Why does Spamhaus' CBL blocklist return records for 1.1.1.1 and 8.8.8.8?

Tags: ddos

I'm looking up ips with the following code

```
import dns.resolver
resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
resolver.timeout = 0.10
resolver.lifetime = 0.10
resolver.nameservers = ['127.0.0.53']

searchIp = '8.8.8.8'
ipRev =  '.'.join( searchIp.split('.')[::-1])
searchQuery = ipRev+'.'+'cbl.spamhaus.org'
resolver.query(searchQuery,'A')
```

The above returns

```
>>> resolver.query(searchQuery,'A').response
<DNS message, ID 11379>
```

And not what I would expect;

```
dns.resolver.NXDOMAIN: None of DNS query names exist: 8.8.8.8.cbl.spamhaus.org., 8.8.8.8.cbl.spamhaus.org.
```

Is there caching happening? Or is there a problem with the way I'm doing the lookups? Because this really looks like a very obvious false positive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be useful to take a closer look at the answer you get instead of just seeing that you are getting a successful answer back:

```
searchQuery = ipRev+'.'+'cbl.spamhaus.org'
print resolver.query(searchQuery,'A').response
```

results for me in:

```
...
;ANSWER                                                                                                                                                                                      
8.8.8.8.cbl.spamhaus.org. 172732 IN CNAME blocklist.address.is.wrong.spamhaus.org.
blocklist.address.is.wrong.spamhaus.org. 172732 IN A 127.0.0.2
```

A quick search indicates that you'll get this kind of answer when using a non-existing blacklist. In fact, looking at [spamhaus.org](https://www.spamhaus.org/) shows no information about some CBL list. There are SBL, XBL, PBL or DBL lists but no CBL. So you are using a non-existing list. Switching instead for example to `sbl.spamhaus.org` gives you the expected `dns.resolver.NXDOMAIN`.

Comment: I included a sample of the reponse, I should've printed it. Switching to xbl solved this for me. Thanks.